# How to show record details on click of View button in LWC table using Popup window?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

On Account Object, I want to show all contacts of the account in table format & in table, I want to create a View Button. After clicking on View Button, it should open popup window and display contacts details.

Below is the code:

**Controller Class:**

```
public with sharing class viewContacts {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

    public static List<Contact> getContactList(String accountId) {
       system.debug('accountId is:'+accountId);
        return [SELECT Id,Name,Phone from Contact where AccountId=:accountId];

    }
}
```

**JS File:**

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    track,
    api,
    wire
} from 'lwc';
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/viewContacts.getContactList';

export default class ViewContactDetails extends LightningElement {
    @track error;;
    @track contactsList;

    @track createSMSRec;

    @api recordId;
    @track isModalOpen = false;
    @track isViewModalOpen = false;

    @track columns = [

        {

            type: 'button',

            typeAttributes:

            {

                label: 'View',

                name: 'viewRecord',

                title: 'view',

                disabled: false,

                value: 'View',

            }



        },
        {

            label: 'Contact Name',

            fieldName: 'Name',

            type: 'text',

            sortable: true

        },

        {

            label: 'Phone Number',

            fieldName: 'Phone',

            type: 'phone',

            sortable: true

        }


    ];
    @wire(getContactList, {
        accountId: '$recordId'
    })

    wiredContacts({
        error,
        result
    }) {

        if (result) {
            console.log('Displaying Results:');
            this.contactsList = result;

        } else if (error) {

            this.error = error;

        }

    }

    /*

    @wire(createNewSMS, { caseID: '$recordId'})

        wiredcreateSMS({ error, data }) {

            if (data) {

                this.createSMSRec = data;

            } else if (error) {

                this.error = error;

            }

    }
*/
    handleSuccess(event) {

        this.dispatchEvent(

            new ShowToastEvent({

                title: 'Success',

                message: event.detail.apiName + ' created.',

                variant: 'success',

            }),

        );

    }



    handleChange(event) {

        // console.log("You selected an record: " + event.detail.value[0]);

    }





    openModal() {

        // to open modal set isModalOpen tarck value as true

        this.isModalOpen = true;

    }

    closeModal() {

        // to close modal set isModalOpen tarck value as false

        this.isModalOpen = false;

    }



    openViewModal(event) {

        // to open modal set isModalOpen tarck value as true

        this.isViewModalOpen = true;



    }

    closVieweModal() {

        // to close modal set isModalOpen tarck value as false

        this.isViewModalOpen = false;

    }



    submitDetails() {

        // to close modal set isModalOpen tarck value as false

        //Add your code to call apex method or do some processing

        this.isModalOpen = false;

    }
}
```

**HTML File:**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title = "View Contacts">
    <div style="height:500px;">

    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-no-row-hover slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table_striped">

        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th>
                    <div title="action">Action</div>
                </th>

                <th>
                    <div title="name">Contact Name</div>
                </th>

                <th>
                    <div title="phone">Phone</div>
                </th>
               
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <template for:each={contactsList} for:item="cnt">

                <tr key={cnt} class="tblRow">

                    <td data-label="viewBtn">

                        <div>
                            <lightning-button variant="brand" onclick={openViewModal} label="View"></lightning-button>
                        </div>

                    </td>

                    <td data-label="ContactName">

                        <div>{cnt.Name}</div>

                    </td>

                    <td data-label="PhoneNumber">

                        <div>{cnt.Phone}</div>

                    </td>
                  

                </tr>

            </template>

        </tbody>

    </table>



<template if:true={isViewModalOpen}>

    <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC starts here -->

   <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC starts here -->
   <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01"
   aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1"
   class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
   <div class="slds-modal__container">
       <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC header here -->
       <header class="slds-modal__header">
           <button
               class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse"
               title="Close" onclick={closeModal}>
               <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                   alternative-text="close" variant="inverse" size="small">
               </lightning-icon>
               <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
           </button>
           <h2 id="modal-heading-01"
               class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Confirmation
               Title</h2>
       </header>
       <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC body starts here -->
       <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium"
           id="modal-content-id-1">
           <center>
               
               <p>Here I want to show Record Details</p>
           </center>

       </div>
      
   </div>
</section>

</template>



<!--</lightning-record-edit-form> -->

</div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

***Can we add lightning-record-view-form under popup window to show Contact record details?***

When I try to add above components on Account Detail page, it is not showing contact details due to which I am not able to work on View Button?

Can someone please help me here?

Error that I am getting in Console log:
[image]

Comment: Can you see anything in    console.log('Displaying Results:'); ?

Comment: Nothing in console log but its making a server call since I am getting parent record id in system debug. Not sure what's the issue in wire service

Comment: can you try this?

 if (result) {
            console.log('Displaying Results:');
            this.contactsList = result;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

        } else if (error) {

            this.error = error;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));

        }

Comment: Its not going to debug logs but an exception is occured. I have attached screenshot for more details. Please check

Comment: Could you try to set '@track contactsList;' to empty array? So '@track contactsList= [];' I think that your component is trying to set something undefined under iteration and returning an error because of that. Long shot though

Comment: That error is gone but this error Error: [LWC error]: The `appendChild` method is available only on elements that use the `lwc:dom="manual"` directive is remains. Not sure if it is related to this component. Still nothing of console log is ther.

Comment: would it be possible for you to test the same code in your personal org?